# JavaScript convert String into Array Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, underscore.js

How do I convert string to array object.

I have string

let colors = "[red, blue, green]"

and would like to convert as

String[] colors = ["red", "blue", "green"]

Is there any inbuilt functions available for this conversion?

Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: Are you trying to convert JavaScript to Java?

Comment: No not java, just looking for any inbuilt functions my ES6 . my question had typo.      
let colors = "[red, blue, green]" to let colors : string[] = ["red", "blue", "green"]

Comment: If you're looking for a built-in way, there isnt. However [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is very close, you just need to remove the brackets from the string first. See my answer

Comment: It looks like you didn't try anything

Answer (score 3):

I would follow @Jannes Carpentier 's approach - but to givae an alternative - you can use slice to get the text (non-brackets) portion  of the string and then split on the "`,` " to get an array of the text items and then re-assign it to the original variable.

```js
let colors = "[red, blue, green]"

colors = colors.slice(1,-1).split(', ');

console.log(colors); // gives ["red", "blue", "green"]
```

Comment: Thank you for response.

Comment: Even simpler: `colors.slice(1, -1)`

Comment: Thanks @Bergi - Updated to your suggestion - I like the concise approach of that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Bergi yes much easy. like build in function style

Answer (score 2):

First remove the brackets

Then split on `", "`

```js
let colors = "[red, blue, green]"

colors = colors.replace(/([\[\]])/g, "");
colors = colors.split(", ");

console.log(colors);
```

Instead of replacing all `[ ]` you could also remove the first and last character from the string

And then split on `", "`

```js
let colors = "[red, blue, green]"

colors = colors.substring(1, colors.length - 1);
colors = colors.split(", ");

console.log(colors);
```

Comment: I like more your 2nd one. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

If your data isn't formatted in any common standard, you are unlikely to find a prebuilt data parser. If you have control over the input string, it would be better to format it as a json string as follows: '["red", "green", "blue"]' Then you can easily take it apart with JSON.parse().

The other two answers have very satisfactory parsers for your data, however, I prefer not to count on the existence of whitespace in my input. A parser such as

```
function customParse(data) {
  return data
    .substring(1, data.length -1)
    .split(",", data)
    .map(trim);
}

console.log(customParse("[red, blue,green]"));
```

will work regardless of whitespace.

Comment: I do not have control over the response. I am getting array as string to my UI layer. I needed those values for comparison purposes.

Comment: Your question has 3 acceptable answers. You should accept one of them.